# why draggable="true" prevents scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have draggable element and scrollable container, but I cannot scroll container while dragging, why does it happens?
Is there a way to allow scrolling while dragging?

```css
.container{
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: green
}
.draggable{
  background:red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="draggable" draggable="true"> draggable </p>

<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
<div>qwerty</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When an element has the draggable attribute set to "true", it can be moved around by the user with a mouse or touch interaction. When a user interacts with the element, the browser needs to determine whether the user intends to move the element or scroll the page.

By default, the browser prioritizes scrolling when a user swipes or scrolls using a mouse wheel or trackpad. However, when an element has `draggable="true"`, the browser prioritizes the element's movement over scrolling. This means that if the user interacts with the element and tries to swipe or scroll, the browser will interpret the gesture as an attempt to move the element instead of scrolling the page.

To prevent this behavior and allow scrolling, you can add the touch-action CSS property to the element with a value of pan-y or auto. This tells the browser to prioritize vertical scrolling for touch interactions on that element, while still allowing the element to be draggable.

For example:

```
<div draggable="true" style="touch-action: pan-y;">

  <!-- Element content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation><, I tried to add prop ```touch-action: pan-y;``` to my ```p .draggable``` element, but that still does not allows scrolling while dragging( - Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I mean, that is not scrolling onMousewheel event(